# Cron job, random start but within timeframe

Tags: cron

I want a script to run once a day, everyday, starting any time between 0900 and 1200.
I'm not completely sure about the dash syntax - does it mean that the script will run EVERY hour between `9-12`, or that it will start RANDOMLY between `9-12`? Because I need the latter.

Answer (score 9):

I've never seen a cron implementation which has a way to run a job at a random time. It's an odd requirement. As the documentation states, `9-12` is a shortcut for `9,10,11,12`, and means every hour from 9 to 12.

If you want to run a job at a random time, run the job at the start of the interval, and add a random delay. For example, to run at a random hour between 9 and 12:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
0 9 * * * sleep $((3600 * (RANDOM \% 4))); do_stuff
```

Note that `RANDOM` requires bash or ksh, it may not be available in the default shell.

If you want to run at a random time between 9 and 12, with second resolution, you can use `RANDOM % 10800` as the delay, but because `RANDOM` is in the range 0..32767, there will be a bias towards delays between 0 and 32768 % 10800 = 368. To avoid this bias:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
0 9 * * * max=$((32768/10800*10800)); while delay=$RANDOM; ((delay > max)); do :; done; sleep $((delay \% 10800)); do_stuff
```

Comment: "It's an odd requirement." I disagree. Many applications, especially those that need to periodically check in with a server (such as package managers or configuration management clients), need to splay their execution times in order to avoid a [thundering herd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem) situation. In fact, many such applications have splay options built-in (e.g. `--randomwait` argument to yum or `--splay` argument to chef-client), but for those that do not, a random execution time would be a helpful feature to have in a job scheduler.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34815984/5419599

Comment: Note that when used in crontab, `%` must be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up having similar requirement for python scripts, but ended up implementing this via the script itself, using random + sleep functions, then launching the cron job @ midnight

```
from time import sleep
import random

sleep_time = random.randint(0,7200)  #7200 seconds = 2 hours * 60 min * 60 sec
print(sleep_time)
sleep(sleep_time)
```

Comment: This is how common scripts from Linux distros often randomise start time: Have a fixed time, then sleep at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

On OpenBSD, from release 6.7 (in snapshots since about Apr 15 2020), you can specify random time intervals with `~` in a crontab file:

> A random value (within the legal range) may be obtained by using the `~`
>   character in a field.  The interval of the random value may be specified
>   explicitly, for example `0~30` will result in a random value between 0
>   and 30 inclusive.  If either (or both) of the numbers on either side of
>   the `~` are omitted, the appropriate limit (low or high) for the field
>   will be used.

```
30~45 * * * * somecommand
```

would therefore execute `somecommand` at some point in the 15 minuter interval between half past each hour and quarter to the next hour, every hour.

Since the use of `~` picks a *single*, but random, value in the given range, a crontab entry such as

```
~ 9~11 * * * somecommand
```

would run the command as requested in the question, at some point between 9:00 am and noon (11:59 am), every day.

See also

- [The OpenBSD `crontab(5)` manual](https://man.openbsd.org/crontab.5).

Caveat (not mentioned in the manual): The random times are picked randomly, but they are *fixed* until the crontab is reloaded, i.e. until the cron daemon restarts or when the crontab is edited with `crontab -e`.  This would therefore not provide you with a new random value for each run of the job, like using `sleep` with `$RANDOM` would do.

Answer (score 1):

If using a modern Linux distro you most likely have systemd running on it, in which case you can use a [systemd timer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/Timers) instead of cron. Here's the timer config for 'every day at a random time between 0900 and 1200:

```
# foo.timer

[Unit]
Description=Run every day between 0900 to 1200 randomly

[Timer]
OnCalendar=09:00:00
RandomizedDelaySec=10800

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

And a service definition file for the corresponding service that will be run by the timer:

```
# foo.service

[Unit]
Description=My service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/echo hello world
```

The key is the `RandomizedDelaySec=` configuration which comes built in with systemd: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#RandomizedDelaySec=

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers rely on non-portable features or bashisms- since you've asked for dash, here is a portable solution:

```
0 9 * * * sleep $(echo | awk '{srand(); print rand()*3600*3}') && whatever_you_wanted_to_do
```

This uses only utilities and syntax guaranteed to exist under POSIX, and should work on any UNIX even with the barest of minimal installs.